# Decoupling capacitors in power card

Tags: power, filter

This is a power card. I have highlighted the part between the EMI filter and the Transient protection module. Are those capacitors needed? As per the data sheet, there has to be an R*C cell.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please don't delete the schematic image from your question. The question makes no sense without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Are those capacitors needed?*

The [Gaia FGDS-10A-50V data sheet (page 3)](https://gaia-converter.com/docs/ds/FGDS-10A-50V.pdf) recommends this: -

[image: FGDS-10A-50V]

[image]

So, if you want "better EMI performance" then you need to fit capacitors that together in parallel are equivalent to the values implied in the data sheet (extract directly above). Having said that, your circuit appears to have 3 x 220 μF capacitors in parallel and this is greater than what the table covers so, maybe you might be able to remove one capacitor but, I'd generally just leave it as it is unless there is a pressing reason to change it that you have not disclosed.

Additionally, the [Gaia LGDS-300 data sheet (page 10)](https://gaia-converter.com/docs/ds/LGDS300.pdf) states this: -

[image]

So, if you want to meet the MIL standards for EMI compliance, you fit them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andy aka for providing a datasheet. Section 4.3 discusses the R*C* network and explains that the purpose is to damp the high Q resonance of the inductors and capacitors inside the FGDS-10A-50V. The relevant sentence in this case is this one (pg 4):

"In most applications a low ESR aluminium electrolytic capacitor can be used for damping the network and it’s **internal
ESR value will be enough to dampen the input voltage without adding external resistor.**"